# Generate request/response template json from yaml spec

Tags: rest, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a usecase where we are trying to build a generic HTTP client which can call multiple APIs from various services. I was wondering if there is a way to generate the request and response and store it.Once the event is triggered, the generic HTTP client will pick up the template and make a call to the API.

So far, I have come across Swagger-UI which basically renders this information. However there is no easy to use API on the backend to invoke the service. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more what you are trying to achieve? I'm afraid your use case is not completely clear - can you add some examples? Why is a generic HTTP request library (e.g. Python requests) not enough? Are the target APIs known is advance or will they be arbitrary APIs? What programming language are you using?

Comment: Do you need something like [Swagger JS](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-js) (for JavaScript) or [Bravado](https://github.com/Yelp/bravado) (for Python)?